# 3DS + and - charging contacts?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I am trying to charge my 3DS without the original charger via USB cable (by stripping the wires). On the back of the 3DS, which metal contact is positive and which is negative?

Comment: The 3DS claims to take 4.6V input (as marked on the case and the charger). 5V input *may* cause damage or shorten life.

Comment: Didn't answer my question, but I checked it out and USB input should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the port like so:

[image: 3DS Charge Port]

The left hole is Negative and the right hole is positive. I also believe the pads are the same.

- Left Pad (-)
- Right Pad (+)

5V also shouldn't hurt it because the charging circuit inside the 3DS should prevent anything bad from happening. I see a lot of 3rd party chargers that are just straight through USB to charge-port.

Hope this helps!